# R - How to split/combine columns for multiple variables

Tags: r, statistics, tidyr

I'm quite the novice at R and I haven't been able to find an answer of how to split a column with multiple variables (sample 1-4) into separate columns whilst moving the data it correlates with. Here's an example:

```
Samples     Content
Sample 1    70.7
Sample 1    91.6
Sample 1    92.6
Sample 1    65.2
Sample 1    80.0
Sample 1    82.1
Sample 1    88.1
Sample 1    92.2
Sample 1    53.3
Sample 1    80.0
Sample 1    60.3
Sample 1    89.7
Sample 1    84.8
Sample 1    94.0
Sample 1    71.8
Sample 1    76.9
Sample 1    91.4
Sample 1    57.9
Sample 1    61.9
Sample 1    71.5
Sample 2    88.7
Sample 2    67.6
Sample 2    61.7
Sample 2    70.8
Sample 2    45.3
Sample 2    55.6
Sample 2    64.6
Sample 2    62.7
Sample 2    72.4
Sample 2    46.8
Sample 2    59.0
Sample 2    63.7
Sample 2    67.0
Sample 2    71.6
Sample 2    48.3
Sample 2    55.6
Sample 2    62.5
Sample 2    60.0
Sample 2    72.9
Sample 2    47.4
Sample 3    42.3
Sample 3    48.2
Sample 3    64.0
Sample 3    33.3
Sample 3    19.0
Sample 3    41.0
Sample 3    53.1
Sample 3    46.5
Sample 3    30.0
Sample 3    43.4
Sample 3    43.7
Sample 3    92.0
Sample 3    53.0
Sample 3    33.0
Sample 3    48.4
Sample 3    43.2
Sample 3    41.8
Sample 3    62.5
Sample 3    33.3
Sample 3    49.3
Sample 4    51.8
Sample 4    57.3
Sample 4    43.3
Sample 4    42.3
Sample 4    37.6
Sample 4    54.9
Sample 4    71.1
Sample 4    33.8
Sample 4    43.1
Sample 4    39.1
Sample 4    63.0
Sample 4    74.0
Sample 4    31.0
Sample 4    48.3
Sample 4    42.9
Sample 4    62.2
Sample 4    35.4
Sample 4    33.8
Sample 4    40.7
Sample 4    41.2
```

I tried tidyr with no success. I want the output to be something like this;

```
Sample 1    Sample 2    Sample 3    Sample 4
70.7    88.7    42.3    51.8
91.6    67.6    48.2    57.3
92.6    61.7    64.0    43.3
65.2    70.8    33.3    42.3
80.0    45.3    19.0    37.6
82.1    55.6    41.0    54.9
88.1    64.6    53.1    71.1
92.2    62.7    46.5    33.8
53.3    72.4    30.0    43.1
80.0    46.8    43.4    39.1
60.3    59.0    43.7    63.0
89.7    63.7    92.0    74.0
84.8    67.0    53.0    31.0
94.0    71.6    33.0    48.3
71.8    48.3    48.4    42.9
76.9    55.6    43.2    62.2
91.4    62.5    41.8    35.4
57.9    60.0    62.5    33.8
61.9    72.9    33.3    40.7
71.5    47.4    49.3    41.2
```

Many thanks, if a solution is identified, is there an answer if I wanted to do the reciprocate?

Extra - Is there any way to preform a t-test on data which is stacked in one column such as the first example without having to transform it?

Comment: `do.call(cbind, split(df$Content, df$Samples)`

Comment: look into `tidyr::spread` or `reshape2::dcast(?)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You may be having the "duplicate identifiers" issue using `tidyr::spread`. You need first to generate unique combinations of Sample + identifier, which you can do like this (assuming data frame named `df1`):

   ```
   library(tidyverse) # for dplyr + tidyr
   df1 %>% 
     group_by(Samples) %>% 
     mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
     spread(Samples, Content) %>%
     select(-id)
   ```
2. > "if I wanted to do the reciprocate"

Do you mean go the other way, from the wide form back to the original long form? Then you use `gather`. Add this to the end of the code above and see what happens:

```
%>% gather(Samples, Content)
```

3. t-test: there are lots of ways you could run a t-test on the long format data. For example, a base R way to compare Samples 1 and 2 might be:

   ```
   t.test(df1[df1$Samples == "Sample 1", "Content"], 
          df1[df1$Samples == "Sample 2", "Content"])
   ```

Comment: Fantastic thank you very much for being so helpful both of you! :)

Comment: glad this got posted before the question was closed down!

Answer (score 1):

As the number of elements for each 'Sample' is the same, we can use `unstack` from `base R`

```
unstack(df1, Content~Samples)
#    Sample.1 Sample.2 Sample.3 Sample.4
#1      70.7     88.7     42.3     51.8
#2      91.6     67.6     48.2     57.3
#3      92.6     61.7     64.0     43.3
#4      65.2     70.8     33.3     42.3
#5      80.0     45.3     19.0     37.6
#6      82.1     55.6     41.0     54.9
#7      88.1     64.6     53.1     71.1
#8      92.2     62.7     46.5     33.8
#9      53.3     72.4     30.0     43.1
#10     80.0     46.8     43.4     39.1
#11     60.3     59.0     43.7     63.0
#12     89.7     63.7     92.0     74.0
#13     84.8     67.0     53.0     31.0
#14     94.0     71.6     33.0     48.3
#15     71.8     48.3     48.4     42.9
#16     76.9     55.6     43.2     62.2
#17     91.4     62.5     41.8     35.4
#18     57.9     60.0     62.5     33.8
#19     61.9     72.9     33.3     40.7
#20     71.5     47.4     49.3     41.2
```

No external packages are used

---

If the number of 'Sample' elements are different, then `dcast` from `data.table` can be used (works in both cases)

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), rowid(Samples)~Samples, value.var = "Content")
```

Comment: Fantastic thank you very much for being so helpful both of you! :)